# Number of undirected graphs with $n$ vertices and $k$ edges (inclusive of simple, non-simple, isomorphic, and disconnected graphs)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given the constraints (or non-constraints rather), is there a closed solution on a set of labeled vertices?

One way I looked at this problem is by trying to implement a constrained stars-and-bars technique on the diagonal and diagonal-exclusive half of the $n \times n $ adjacency matrix, but I'm not getting any good leads.

It seems there are multiple definitions of a self-loop in undirected graphs. In the context of this question, I define a self-loop to represent a degree of $2$ in an undirected graph.

Comment: Any why wouldn't it just be $\binom{k+m-1}k$ where $k=\binom n2+n=\binom{n+1}2?$

Comment: $n$ and $k$ should be independent in the context of my question. As an example, how many graphs have five vertices and seven edges?

Comment: A graph (undirected, without loops or multiple edges) on 5 vertices has 10 "potential" edges, and there are 10-choose-7 ways to choose 7 of these edges, so there are 10-choose-7 (labeled) graphs. That's 120.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\binom{k+m-1}k$ where $m=\binom n2+n=\binom{n+1}2.$ In other words, you have $m=\binom{n+1}2$ matrix entries to fill in with nonnegative integers adding up to $k,$ right?

Comment: Sorry @Gerry Myerson, I meant given the constraints of my original question. So including loops, multiple edges, and disconnections.

Comment: For $5$ vertices and $7$ edges is the answer $\binom{21}7$?

Comment: OK, then, with 5 vertices and 7 edges, you have 15 nonnegative integers (ten edges, 5 loops) adding up to 7, so 21-choose-14, which is, indeed, 21-choose-7.

Comment: @bof yes, you're correct about how many matrix entries I need to fill in. However, I define loops in an undirected graph to be representative of two edges (having a degree of 2), so that formula you mentioned would be assuming that loops could be represented as only one edge.

Comment: i.e. the diagonal of the adjacency matrix cannot contain any 1's (only even numbers)

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, that's not correct in my context. As I mentioned earlier, loops count as two edges, so they must be constrained to be under $k$ and be even.

Comment: Huh? You count a loop as two edges? So, if a graph has one vertex $v$ and one loop, it has ***two*** edges? And the vertex $v$ has degree ***four***? (Because the degree-sum is equal to twice the number of edges.)

Comment: Last I checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory) the degree-sum is simply the number of edges incident on the vertex, with loops counted twice. The vertex $v$ would have a degree of 2 if it had just one loop.

Comment: According to you, how many (labeled) graphs are there with $2$ vertices and $k$ edges?

Comment: if k is even, then $3(k/2)+3$; otherwise, $3(k+1)/2 + 1$

Comment: OK, so we're talking about the number of (non-negative integer) solutions to $$2(x_1+\cdots+x_5)+y_1+\cdots+y_{10}=7$$ I'll get back to you....

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes that sounds like the right idea! Thank you for simplifying the problem.

Comment: So with $2$ vertices and $k=1$ edges you get $4$ graphs? I don't think that can be right, I only see $3$ places to put the edge.

Comment: Nobody counts a loop as two edges. A loop is one edge. Like any other edge, a loop contributes $2$ to the degree-sum. An ordinary edge $uv$ contributes $2$ to the degree-sum by contributing $2$ to the degree of $u$ and $1$ to the degree of $v;$ a loop $vv$ contributes $2$ to the degree-sum by contributing $2$ to the degree of $v.$ The total number of edges (including loops) is half the sum of all the matrix entries; the number of loops is half the sum of the diagonal entries.

Comment: That certainly is the case from your school of thought. There is definitely some controversy over this concept; see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory) and here https://www.quora.com/In-an-undirected-graph-what-is-the-degree-of-a-vertex-with-a-self-loop; I still ask the question given my perception of a loop having a degree of 2 in an undirected graph; please let's not start a discussion here now that definitions are settled.

Comment: Sorry, regarding your doubt about 2 vertices and $k=1$ edges, I meant $3(k-1)/2 + 1$

Comment: Can you link to one site that counts a loop as two edges? Every site you've linked to uses the standard terminology: a loop at vertex $v$ is ***one*** edge, and therefore contributes ***two*** to the degree of $v$.

Comment: A degree is the number of edges incident on a vertex. If a loop has a degree of two, the number of edges incident on it is two. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory) and page 5 of Diestel http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/GrTh5_Ch1.pdf

Comment: In any case, you at least agree that a loop has a degree of 2. Let's agree with your rhetoric regarding a loop visually; it doesn't change the problem. We're still focusing on the degrees here in the adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the example of graphs with five vertices and seven edges. In the comments, after a lot of back-and-forth to clarify the nature of the graphs being counted, it was established that the number of these graphs is the number of (non-negative integer) solutions to
$$
2(x_1+\cdots+x_5)+y_1+\cdots+y_{10}=7. 
$$
This is the number of non-negative integer solutions to
$$
z_1+\cdots+z_5+y_1+\cdots+y_{10}=7
$$
with $z_j$ all even. This is the coefficient of $x^7$ in
$$
f(x)=(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots)^5(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^{10}.
$$
We have
$$
f(x)=(1-x^2)^{-5}(1-x)^{-10}=(1+5x^2+{6\choose2}x^4+\cdots)(1+10x+{11\choose2}x^2+\cdots)
$$
by the Binomial Theorem. So, the answer will be
$$
{16\choose7}+5{14\choose5}+{6\choose2}{12\choose3}+{7\choose3}10=25100
$$

The method should apply for any number of vertices and edges, and result in a sum of products of pairs of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider labeled graphs, there are $n^2$ legitimate spots for an edge (if you allow loops). Since you accept the non-simple graphs (so parallel edges), each of the $k$ edges can be put in any of those spots. In the end, you get $(n^2)^k$ which is equal to
$ n^{2k}$.

Comment: You mean there are ${n}\choose{2}$ spots for an edge (loop exclusive) and $n$ spots for a loop, giving a total of ($n$ $+$ ${n}\choose{2}$)$^k$ possible combinations right? How do you account for the constraint where there can only be a certain number of loops in proportion to the non-loop edges? My definition of a loop (consistent with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) includes that a loop constitutes a degree of 2. That restricts the different combinations of diagonal entries and diagonal-exclusive half entries in the adjacency matrix.

Comment: There are infinitely mny graphs with one vertex and no edges. They are all isomorphic, but according to your header, that doesn't stop you from counting them all.